# Figuring out how to create "Option Pages" in WordPress admin

Tags: customization, wp-admin

I'm having a static front page, in which I plan to have the little bits like text, buttons, and other plain stuff editable through `wp-admin`.

I plan to make it simple, just like in "Settings > General" (`options-general.php`), with input values to fill by the users. However, I've been encountering difficulties to achieve that.

I've been following the tutorial from [Tutsplus](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-custom-admin-pages-in-wordpress-4--cms-27018) but they hooked into the_content instead, with only one value. Which seems to be inserted into `wp_options` in the MySQL table. I want to put it into a separate, new table. For example, `wp_frontpage`.

Here is the mostly unaltered code in `views/settings.php`

```
<div class="wrap">

<h1><?php echo esc_html( get_admin_page_title() ); ?></h1>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo esc_html( admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ) ); ?>">

    <div id="universal-message-container">
        <h2>Front</h2>

        <div class="options">
            <p>
                <label>What message would you like to display above each post?</label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="acme-message"
                value="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->deserializer->get_value( 'tutsplus-custom-data' ) ); ?>"
                />
            </p>
    </div><!-- #universal-message-container -->

    <?php
        wp_nonce_field( 'acme-settings-save', 'acme-custom-message' );
        submit_button();
    ?>

</form>
```

I tried looking at the official guide: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

But apparently the page is obsolete since it didn't do anything.

Any guide to do this?

Comment: If you want to use a table other then wp_options then you’re not creating an options page. You’re doing something else. You’ll need to handle the creation of the admin pages and saving data yourself. That tutorial won’t be relevant. Besides, custom fields/meta boxes or the Customiser would be much more appropriate for what you’re trying to do.

Comment: @JacobPeattie thank you for the comment. Could you please point out to a more relevant tutorial, perhaps for the custom fields/meta boxes? Or the Customizer plugin (I assume it's a plugin, searched for it and found three different ones)? I've been trying to figure this out but not sure what/how to do it...

Comment: @JacobPeattie oh okay I just realized what you mean. I ended up using Advanced Custom Fields plugin to make this a lot easier. Thank you!